# fastify-http-proxy: setting up dynamic upstream and dynamic authentication

Tags: fastify

I would like to use fastify-http-proxy plugin with fastify-3.x.

However I am facing a few difficulties when trying to use it per my application.

Let me explain my requirement:

In my application, user is going to be presented a set of environments. When user selects a particular environment (say env-1), based on that I need to make a REST API call to another service, passing the env-1 ID to get the IP address of my upstream and the authorization token (Basic auth of username:password) for that upstream.

When user selects another environment (say env-2), I should "re-set" the new upstream and new authorization token based on env-2.

For that I would like to dynamically register the upstream and the auth token. I saw the examples of fastify-http-proxy [testcases](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-http-proxy/blob/master/test/test.js). However all the examples just adding the `replyOptions` during the `server.register(proxy, ...)` step.

I understand somehow I need to override the `getUpstream` and `rewriteRequestHeader`. However not able to get an idea how can I defer it to the later stage where based on environment selection, I can write logic by calling different services' APIs to get the upstream endpoint IP address and upstream authorization information.

Along with that, if I want to just log some information (say some telemetry information .. how much time it to proxy the request to upstream server), what is the best way to do it.

Just to demonstrate it in a code snippet:

```js
 const server = Fastify()
    server.register(proxy, {
      upstream: '',
      replyOptions: {
        getUpstream: function (original, base) {
          // Here I want to pass the selected environment ID
          // Based on the environment ID, will make other services' API call to get the upstream 
          return `<...>`
        }
        rewriteRequestHeaders: (originalRequest, headers) => {
           // Here I want to pass the selected environment ID
           // Based on the environment ID, will make other services' API call to get the envAuth
            return {
                ...headers,
                "Authorization": envAuth
            };
        }
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

The `getUpstream` and `rewriteRequestHeaders` parameters are sync functions, so you can't execute async operations such as an HTTP call.

One option to do so is a local cache you can use in those parameters

Pseudo code:

```js
const cache = {}
server.post('/select-env', async (request, reply) => {
  const data = await datasource.load(request.userId, request.body.env)
  cache[request.userId] = { data }
  return 'loaded'
})

server.register(proxy, {
  upstream: '',
  replyOptions: {
    getUpstream: function (original, base) {
      const userId = original.headers['user-id']
      return cache[userId].data.upstream
    },
    rewriteRequestHeaders: (originalRequest, headers) => {
      // Here I want to pass the selected environment ID
      // Based on the environment ID, will make other services' API call to get the envAuth
      const userId = originalRequest.headers['user-id']
      return {
        ...headers,
        Authorization: cache[userId].data.auth,
      }
    },
  },
})
```

The other options are:

- implement this feature and send a PR to https://github.com/fastify/fastify-reply-from
- note that you can't access the Fastify's `Request` object using the `origin` argument. You could access it by adding this feature too to the module.

Comment: Thanks. So the caller needs to set the 'user-id' in the request header as context of every API call?

Comment: Yes, that is one option. The issue is that you can't get the fastify's request object and its decorators right now, without fixing the actual implementation.

Comment: Basically trying to understand what is this original object inside the sync methods? If the api caller set the request header appropriately with 'user-id', can I able to get it inside the sync methods?

Comment: The `origin` argument is equal to `request.raw` https://github.com/fastify/fastify-reply-from/blob/73450cdb78124a131e9ac5eb35a37d1aa2b326df/index.js#L39
Yes, adding to the header make it accessible

Comment: Thanks sir. This is really helpful. And how may I log the time taken in the proxy and the actual upstream call such that later on I can equipped with triaging any slow response field  issue?

Comment: Another last question is: are these sync methods like 'getUpstream' and 'replyRequestHeaders' getting called for every API invocation? Like every proxing to the upstream will have these sync methods being called ? Thanks.

Comment: > for every API invocation? 
yes, it is

> And how may I log the time taken
this is already happening if you turn on the logs, or you need to use the onRequest/onSend hooks